# How to create partition after ubuntu installed

Tags: 13.04, 14.04, partitioning

I bought my laptop online with Ubuntu OS pre-installed and with default partitions.

Problem: How to change the partition size or create a new one ?

[Here is an image showing my current partitions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/weIIr.png)

Comment: You just need to install gparted utility. sudo apt-get install gparted. Its like disk manager.

Answer (score 0):

Use Gparted. But be carefull when use it.Otherwise your data will loose. This link could help you http://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/gparted.html